# How to sort autosuggestions in VS Code (intellisense)?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, autosuggest

I use [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for daily basis work but it's a bit irritating that autosuggestions are placed "randomly" in the list, like on `.gif` below.

At the top are displayed *snippets* from [Reactjs code snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xabikos.ReactSnippets) plugin and the most important in this case `props` are displayed at the bottom of the list, I mean:

```
children
exact
from
key
path 
// etc
```

Is there any way to configure VS Code to display autosuggestions in specific order?

I've found that VS Code has specific property for [snippetSuggestions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) but it hasn't helped, from my settings:

```
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
```

[image: GIF which shows the problem]

OS, versions

```
vs code 1.14.2
macOS 10.12.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the settings, try :

```
{
  "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"
}
```

Comment: I accepted your answer because it forced me to double check documentation and everything is right when I set `"editor.snippetSuggestions": "bottom"`.